# Adding image to JPanel in GUI

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

It says the constructor JPanel(ImageIcon) is undefined.

Here is partial of my code

```
public Method_1(Test aa) {
this.aa = aa;
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
setBounds(100, 100, 730, 540);
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
setContentPane(contentPane);
contentPane.setLayout(null);

//JPanel panel = new JPanel();
BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("method_1.png"));
JPanel picLabel = new JPanel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
add(picLabel);
picLabel.setBounds(12, 34, 369, 175);
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Use `JPanel#add` and a `JLabel`, add the label to the panel. See [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Comment: The error message says exactly what the problem is: [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) does not have a constructor that takes a single ImageIcon as a parameter.

Comment: `setBounds(100, 100, 730, 540);`  Better to `pack()` (after following the sage advice of @MadProgrammer and after adding components).

Comment: @AndrewThompson this line `JPanel picLabel = new JPanel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
JPanel picLabel = new JPanel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
```

To:

```
JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
```

Comment: This gives a Unhandled exception type IOException error on `BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("method_1.png"));`

Comment: That's a different type of error (run time rather than compile time). The message should give you some more information about what is wrong. If you can't figure it out, you need to ask another question.